# querying multiple tables with multiple GET functions using 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query 6 separate tables in my mysql database, the structures are as follows;

```
item
```

itemitemid | item | description | brand | date | time | path |

```
actor
```

actoractorid | name | actorthumb | bio |

```
brand
```

brandbrandid | brandname | description | image |

```
movie
```

moviemovieid | title | genre | year | moviethumb | synopsis|

```
user
```

userid | name | surname | email | password |

```
request
```

requestid | userid | itemid | brandid | movieid | actorid | content | requestdate |

By clicking a link to a page called style.php using the get commands I can view the request and the info within it by pulling it from the joined tables. For example where the requestid=1 I can see the movie in the request, the actor in the movie, the item of clothing they were wearing and its brand. By using the following 4 querys;

```
Movie
$requestid = $_GET['requestid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM movie, request WHERE movie.movieid = 
request.movieid and requestid = ".$requestid;

Actor
$requestid = $_GET['requestid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM actor, request WHERE actor.actorid = 
request.actorid and requestid = ".$requestid;

Item
$requestid = $_GET['requestid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM item, request WHERE item.itemid = 
request.itemid and requestid = ".$requestid;

Brand
$requestid = $_GET['requestid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM brand, request WHERE brand.brandid = 
request.brandid and requestid = ".$requestid;
```

Therefore I would like to combine the 4 querys above into 1 single query that would allow me to show all the info, including querying the user and request tables to show who logged the request, please advise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying multiple tables using mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779968/querying-multiple-tables-using-mysql)

Comment: Why why why why why **why** no SQL injection prevention? Who is teaching this stuff?!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM request r
INNER JOIN  movie m ON m.movieid = r.requestid
INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actorid = r.requestid
INNER JOIN item i ON i.itemid = r.requestid
INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brand_id = r.requestid
WHERE r.requestid = {your request id}
```

Of course, if there is a possibility one of the joins will fail (e.g., a movie without a brand) then use a left join instead.

Also, isnt a bit strange that all of your primary keys are equal? You could get away with never selecting from the request table if this is truly the case:

```
SELECT * FROM movie m
INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actorid = m.movieid
INNER JOIN item i ON i.itemid = m.movieid
INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brand_id = m.movieid
WHERE m.movieid = {your request id}
```

Comment: Both of these queries fail to run;        Unable to perform query
select r.requestid, m.*, a.*, i.*, b.* FROM request r INNER JOIN movie m ON m.movieid = r.movieid INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actorid = r.actorid INNER JOIN item i ON i.itemid = r.itemid INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandid = r.brandidWHERE r.requestid = 57

Comment: did you replace the {your request id} with an actual value? I cant really help if you dont give me the error. Also, I dont know your schema so I am just going off the column names you provided but it will at least get you started.

Comment: Not the actual value the variable $requestid which gets the request ID using the GET function. All tables are linked the to request table using the individual table's PK.

Answer (score 1):

First: if you are not using mysql_real_escape_string() on your database inputs, you are asking for a LOT of trouble.

Second: SELECT * should not be used this way... you can get duplicate column names which will make your life very difficult very quickly.  It takes a bit more up-front time, but specify the columns you want to return.

Third: you can join all of these, if you want to get a lot of columns back, and a lot of rows with duplicate data:

```
$requestid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['requestid']);
$query = "select r.requestid, m.*, a.*, i.*, b.* FROM request r INNER JOIN movie m ON m.movieid = r.movieid INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actorid = r.actorid INNER JOIN item i ON i.itemid = r.itemid INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandid = r.brandid WHERE r.requestid = $requestid";
```

you also might want to use LEFT OUTER JOIN if some of these rows won't join up.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your response however this query fails to run;        Unable to perform query
select r.requestid, m.*, a.*, i.*, b.* FROM request r INNER JOIN movie m ON m.movieid = r.movieid INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actorid = r.actorid INNER JOIN item i ON i.itemid = r.itemid INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandid = r.brandidWHERE r.requestid = 57

Comment: looks like the line break before the WHERE clause was removed.  Add a space in there, see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Jeremy I have corrected this, however still the same error SELECT * FROM request rINNER JOIN movie m ON m.movieid = r.requestidINNER JOIN actor a ON a.actorid = r.requestidINNER JOIN item i ON i.itemid = r.requestidINNER JOIN brand b ON b.brand_id = r.requestid WHERE r.requestid = 61

Comment: I still see a lot of phrases mushed up together.  I will change my answer to make it one line, that should help.